# How to show post of specific category?

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

Currently I am querying a post from my custom post type to my custom page template. This is the code I am using

```
 <?php query_posts('post_type=testimonial&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&paged='.
    get_query_var('paged')); ?>

    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <?php the_content(); ?>  


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But I want to query a post from a specific category. For eg. my custom post type is "testimonial" it has 3 categories like category1, category2and category3 . I want to show only the post of category3 in my page template. How can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=3&orderby=rand&numberposts=5'); 
foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Or

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
query_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment either one of the below  as per you requirement.
If you want to query using the id of the category use the first one and replace 99 with your category id.
If you know the  slug of your category use the second one with your category slug(not name).

```
<?php 
    //query_posts('cat=99&post_type=testimonial&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&paged='.get_query_var('paged'));
        //query_posts('category_name=your_category_slug&post_type=testimonial&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>

        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


        <?php the_content(); ?>  


        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

P.S: I recommend you to use wp_query() instead of query_post().